# arraylist sorting in order

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, collections

Attempting to sort arraylist in alphabetical order but the Collection.sort is giving me an error which i do not what to do with it

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

/**
 *
 * @author user
 */
public class BookShelf {

    ArrayList<Book> listOfBooks = new ArrayList<Book>();

    public void addBook(Book book) {
        listOfBooks.add(book);
    }

    public ArrayList<Book> returnListOfBooks() {

        ArrayList<Book> myBook = new ArrayList<Book>(listOfBooks);  
        Collection.sort(myBook);
        return myBook;
    }
```

[image]

any help on how to fix this? thanks a lot!

**Edit***

Just need to return an arraylist of books which is in order, 
after changing to Collections, I've gotten another difficulty.

[image]

I've change collection import as well

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
```

Comment: `Book` doesn’t implement `Comparable` and it would be unnatural to do so. Instead you should implement `Comparator`s for sortable book properties, e.g. author, title, publishing date, etc. Then use `Collections.sort(list, comparatorSpecifyingOrdering);`

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong class.
The Class containing the sort(...) method is Collections not Collection

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the Class `Collections` not `Collection`

```
Collections.sort(myBook);
```

If you don't have duplicates I suggest you to use a `TreeSet`.

Answer (score 0):

Your using user defined custom class So you need to implement comparable/comparator interface to support sorting

see the below example :

```
class Book implements Comparable<Book>
{
    private String bookName;

    public Book(String bookName) {
        this.bookName = bookName;
    }

    public String getBookName() {
        return bookName;
    }

    public void setBookName(String bookName) {
        this.bookName = bookName;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Book o) {
        return this.bookName.compareTo(o.bookName);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 53 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.bookName);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Book other = (Book) obj;
        if (!Objects.equals(this.bookName, other.bookName)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


}
```

**Now You can use sort**

```
//List<Book> list1  = new ArrayList<>();

//Collections.sort(list1);
```